# Divide this algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$2.24 \pi r ^2$ divided by $\frac{24}{3} \pi  r^3$. Can anyone demonstrate the division kindly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2.24\pi r^2$ divided by $\dfrac{24}{3}\pi r^3$

$$=\dfrac{2.24\pi r^2}{\dfrac{24}{3}\pi r^3}$$
$$=\dfrac{2.24\pi r^2}{8\pi r^3}$$
$$=\dfrac{2.24\not\pi \not r^2}{8\not\pi \not r^3}$$
$$=\dfrac{2.24}{8r}$$
$$=\dfrac{0.28}{r}$$